# Create a list using do syntax?

Tags: haskell, monads

I'm relatively new to Haskell. I'm creating a small api/dsl on top of [happstack-lite](http://happstack.com/docs/happstack-lite/happstack-lite.html), which will have an interface more similar to Sinatra, mostly to learn. As a part of this, I want to construct an array using do syntax (basically because it would be prettier than the `msum [route, route, route]` thing. The usage of the monad would look something like this:

```
someFunctionThatMakesStrings :: String

unwrapMyMonadAndGiveMeAList :: MyMonad _ -> [String]

makeAList :: [String]
makeAList = unwrapMyMonadAndGiveMeAList do
    someFunctionThatMakesStrings
    someFunctionThatMakesStrings
    someFunctionThatMakesStrings
    ...
```

So makeAList would return a list with 3 strings. Notice that I would like to use functions inside it that aren't aware of the monad (they just return a string).

I can do this with Writer, but each function called has to be aware of the Writer monad, and it also seems like overkill (I don't need the return type tuple, and the way I got it to work involved lots of wrapping/unwrapping)

I tried using the list monad itself, but it clearly is intended for something different than this.

So which of my assumptions need to change, and then how would I make a new list-construction monad from scratch? How close can I get?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Writer is definitely what you want here; you can avoid "exposing" `Writer` to the outside at the cost of a little more overhead in the definitions themselves:

```
foo :: [String]
foo = execWriter $ do
  tell otherList1
  tell otherList2
  tell otherList3

otherList1 :: [String]
otherList1 = execWriter $ do
  ...
```

i.e., you can keep the use of Writer local to each definition, but you have to wrap each list you want to use as a "source" in `tell`. The key thing here is to use `execWriter`, which discards the result element of the tuple (it's identical to `snd . runWriter`).

However, if you have a lot of definitions like this, I would recommend simply using Writer directly, and only applying `execWriter` in the place where you want the combined result; you can make the types a bit cleaner by defining a synonym like `type Foo = Writer [String]`.

I'm not sure what advantage constructing your own list-creation monad would be; it would end up being identical to `Writer [String]`.

The list monad is indeed irrelevant to what you want to do here.

---

As far as defining your own list-writing monad goes, it's pretty simple:

```
data ListWriter a = ListWriter a [String]

runListWriter :: ListWriter a -> (a, [String])
runListWriter (ListWriter a xs) = (a, xs)

execListWriter :: ListWriter a -> [String]
execListWriter = snd . runListWriter

instance Monad ListWriter where
  return a = ListWriter a []
  ListWriter a xs >>= f = ListWriter b (xs ++ ys)
    where ListWriter b ys = f a
```

The only tricky part is `(>>=)`, where we have to take only the value part of the left argument, feed it into the right hand argument, take it apart, and then combine the two lists inside, wrapping it back up with the result of the right hand side.

Comment: This is great! There is no advantage to constructing my own, I suppose, but since I haven't been able to make one *at all*, I'd like to at least be able to do it to learn.

Comment: When I tried to make one from scratch, I kept getting errors saying that a wasn't equal to b when I tried to write the definition of >>= to ++ the list from the first part to the list from the second. So I really would be interested to see how it would look

Comment: @SeanClarkHess: I've added an example implementation of a Writer for lists.

Comment: Is it possible to remove the "a" (fst) from the ListWriter? It seems like I don't need it, since the functions don't actually need to pass values to each other -- they just need to create independent items for the list. In other words, I'd never use `<-` in my do block for this monad. This doesn't work at all though: https://gist.github.com/1608750. I get: "Kind mis-match. The first argument of `Monad' should have kind `* -> *', but `ListWriter' has kind `*'"

Comment: @SeanClarkHess: Monads have to have a type parameter; that's pretty much the whole point :) Doing away with it gives you a [Monoid](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.4.1.0/doc/html/Data-Monoid.html); of course, that doesn't help you, because you basically want to reap the benefits of `do`-notation for a monoid. In fact, what Writer does is transform a monoid into a monad. You *could* keep the type parameter but not include an actual `a` value in `ListWriter`, passing `undefined` to `f` in `(>>=)`, but it'd be a horrible hack, and not save you any typing.

Comment: ([blaze-html](http://jaspervdj.be/blaze/) does that for performance reasons, for instance.)

Comment: Got it. So I'm sort of stretching the definition of a monad too far. I need to keep the type parameter around for monads to work in general, because usually they only make sense with a type parameter. Thank you for your help.